# How loop one table with parameter from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables below:
table grade is to set the grade to student with allocate qty, zero value means the rest record of students.

```
tblGrade    
Rank    Grade   Allocate Qty    Remark
1   A   3   
2   B+  5   
3   B   5   
4   C   5   
5   D   0   The rest
```

and tblStudentGrade with 2 coluomns StudentID and Score. I need to query this table with parameter from tblGrade to get below result.

```
tblStudentGrade     
StudentID   Score   Grade
S0001   100 A
S0002   99  A
S0014   99  A
S0008   98  B+
S0013   90  B+
S0007   78  B+
S0024   75  B+
S0022   68  B+
S0018   66  B
S0004   59  B
S0006   56  B
S0011   56  B
S0012   56  B
S0017   55  C
S0009   54  C
S0003   50  C
S0023   45  C
S0016   34  C
S0021   26  D
S0005   23  D
S0010   23  D
S0019   23  D
S0020   18  D
S0015   12  D
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried?

Comment: Personally I don't understand what you want.

Comment: So, if the best students only scores 50%, he still gets an A? No wonder education in this country is going to hell

Comment: @siggemannen given a sufficiently hard test and a reasonable class of students, that's an entirely reasonable way to grade.  If an assessment given by the teacher gives the entire class an F, the problem isn't really the _students_...

Comment: This is just dummy data for support logic only, reality score 50% cannot be A grade. thank you all for the supporting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to get the result in a few step. **Use [rank()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead of row_number() so it can handle the tide**.

Step 1. Use window function to calcuate start and end student index based on cumulative AllocateQty. On the last rank, we can use a trick to set end index of last rank to be arbitrary large number (let's say 10,000 is large enough for a reasonable classroom registration size)

Here is the [step 1 query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1a772/6):

```
select
    rank, 
    Grade,
    AllocateQty,
    coalesce(sum(AllocateQty) over (order by rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) + 1 as start_student_index,
    (case when AllocateQty = 0 then 10000 else coalesce(sum(AllocateQty) over (order by rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) + AllocateQty end)  as end_student_index
from
tblGrade
```

| rank | Grade | AllocateQty | start_student_index | end_student_index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | B+ | 5 | 4 | 8 |
| 3 | B | 5 | 9 | 13 |
| 4 | C | 5 | 14 | 18 |
| 5 | D | 0 | 19 | 10000 |

Step 2: Use window functiona and rank() to calculate student_grade_rank and join with grade_index. Bound the join result by student_grade_rank between grade_start_index and grade_end_index.

Here is the [full query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1a772/9):

```
with gradeStudentIndex AS (
select
   rank, 
   Grade,
   AllocateQty,
   coalesce(sum(AllocateQty) over (order by rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) + 1 as start_student_index,
   (case when AllocateQty = 0 then 10000 else coalesce(sum(AllocateQty) over (order by rank ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) + AllocateQty end)  as end_student_index
from
    tblGrade
),
studentGradeRank AS (
select
    studentID,
    score,
    rank() over (order by score desc) as student_grade_rank
from
    tblStudentGrade     
)
select
    sr.studentID,
    sr.score,
    si.grade
from 
    StudentGradeRank sr
join
    gradeStudentIndex si
on
    sr.student_grade_rank BETWEEN si.start_student_index AND si.end_student_index
order by sr.student_grade_rank
```

| studentID | score | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S0001 | 100 | A |
| S0002 | 99 | A |
| S0014 | 99 | A |
| S0008 | 98 | `B+` |
| S0013 | 90 | `B+` |
| S0007 | 78 | `B+` |
| S0024 | 75 | `B+` |
| S0022 | 68 | `B+` |
| S0018 | 66 | B |
| S0004 | 59 | B |
| S0006 | 56 | B |
| S0011 | 56 | B |
| S0012 | 56 | B |
| S0017 | 55 | C |
| S0009 | 54 | C |
| S0003 | 50 | C |
| S0023 | 45 | C |
| S0016 | 34 | C |
| S0021 | 26 | D |
| S0005 | 23 | D |
| S0010 | 23 | D |
| S0019 | 23 | D |
| S0020 | 18 | D |
| S0015 | 12 | D |

Answer (score 1):

Something like below will work:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    Rank int,
    Grade varchar(2),
    AllocateQty int,
    Remark varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO #TempTable (Rank, Grade, AllocateQty, Remark)
VALUES (1, 'A', 3, ''),
       (2, 'B+', 5, ''),
       (3, 'B', 5, ''),
       (4, 'C', 5, ''),
       (5, 'D', 0, 'The rest');

WITH Grades ([rank], [grade]) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rank)
          ,Grade
    FROM #TempTable T
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
        FROM master..spt_values t1 
    ) DS
        ON T.[AllocateQty] >= DS.n
)
SELECT S.*
      ,ISNULL(G.[grade], 'D')
FROM
(
   SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Score, StudentID) AS [Rank]
    FROM tblStudentGrade 
) S
LEFT JOIN Grades G
    ON S.[Rank] = G.[Rank]
```

First, we need to duplicate the grades table using the `AllocateQty` column, and then generate ranks - marks pairs. Then, generate rank for each student and simply join the two data sources.

It's raw. You need to improve depending your real scenario. For example, if two  or more students have the same score, we order by student ID, but maybe these students need to have one rank (use DENSE_RANK in such case for example).